# In c++ clear references to an object when it is deleted

Tags: c++

Lets say A references B.

There can be millions of B's that get referenced by all sorts of different things.

The problem is: B can get deleted and then A ( or any other object ) could be left pointing at garbage and if it goes to use it we will get an AccessViolation.

I think the normal solution is that B needs to maintain a link back so we can null out the reference.

Are there any types of smart pointers that deal with this sort of scenario?  e.g. when B is deleted it will null out the reference to itself?

**Adding an example:**

```
class B
{
  int x;
}

class A
{
   public:
   B* DangerousPointer;
};
```

Let's say B can be deleted at any time, there are millions of B's, and lots of things that can references B's.  I want to know if B has been deleted so I don't access it and get an access violation.  Ideally, I don't want B to have to keep track of all the A's that reference it so that A knows to null out the pointer to B when B is deleted.

**Another question about using weak_ptr:**

Our software currently does not use weak_ptr or shared_ptr at all.  We have a smurfClass (smurf naming convention) that keeps a list of smurfAttributes.

When an smurfClass is deleted, then we also delete all smurfAttributes.
Many other different things may want to reference a smurfAttribute, but we occasionally have issues when we delete a class and all of its attributes and something is left pointing to a smurfAttribute that has been deleted.

Is it possible to hand out a weak_ptr to a smurfAttribute?

From the docs it says:

The weak_ptr class template stores a “weak reference” to an object that’s already managed by a shared_ptr.

Does this mean I can't just pass out a weak_ptr to a smurfAttribute ( since it is not managed by a shared_ptr )?  I don't want to keep the smurfAttribute alive, but I do need to know if it has been deleted, so I don't try to use it.

Comment: shared_ptr? weak_ptr?

Comment: `when B is deleted it will null out the reference to itself?` If you mean a raw `delete` or `delete[]` (on the data itself, not some wrapper) triggering that, no, that doesn't exist

Comment: If you don't want to use something like `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`, or you're performing deletes like deviantfan mentions, you may want to try some kind of Observer pattern, where `A` subscribes to events from `B`, and then `B` updates all of its observers on destruction, and then finishes its destructor. Objects of type `A` would handle the update by nulling out their references to `B`. Could get a little hairy with asynchronous callbacks and notifications though.

Comment: I'm ok with using shared_ptr or weak_ptr.  A needs to be able to know if B has been deleted before attempting to access it.

Comment: @Derek if it was deleted how you think that it would be safe to inter it ? You should considering building your own container to the object it self and when deleting the object the container will still a live

Comment: As the comments and one answer suggest there is a `shared_ptr` in C++11 (or with Boost if you don't have C++11) that will make sure that when B is deleted in one place, it still exists for A to use and will clean itself up only when all references to it have been deleted. It sounds, however, like you want to be able to delete B and have it update A with that information (in other words, not just leave the object around for A to deference). If that's the case, you'll probably have to rethink the architecture of your program a bit.

Comment: @RyanP Exactly this can be accomplished with `weak_ptr`. If you lock a `weak_ptr` it will create a temporary `shared_ptr` to the referenced object. If the referenced object no longer exists, the temporary `shared_ptr` will be empty, which can be checked before accessing it. This way you know if the referenced object still exists and can use it in a safe manner (if it exists it will be kept alive as long as A needs it and cannot cease to exist as long as the temporary `shared_ptr` exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is for.  When you create a `shared_ptr` as long as one reference exist the memory will still be valid.  Here is a little example of using a shared pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void use_shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<int> sp)
{
    std::cout << "in use_shared_ptr() count is: " << sp.use_count() << std::endl;
}

std::shared_ptr<int> function_that_returns_a_local_object()
{
    auto foo = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    std::cout << "just created shared_ptr.  count is: " << foo.use_count() << std::endl;
    use_shared_ptr(foo);
    std::cout << "after use_shared_ptr(foo) count is " << foo.use_count() << std::endl;
    return foo;
} // oh no.  foo gets destroyed here.  what is going to happen?

int main() 
{
    auto bar = function_that_returns_a_local_object();
    std::cout << "back in main count is: " << bar.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
just created shared_ptr.  count is: 1
in use_shared_ptr() count is: 2
after use_shared_ptr(foo) count is 1
back in main count is: 1
```

The plus side to this is there is no manual memory management and then when are completely done with the `shared_ptr` it destroys itself cleaning up the memory that was allocated with [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

You could also hand out a [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).  A `weak_ptr` allows the underlying pointer to be deleted unless you call `lock` which creates a shared pointer that will extend the life of the underlying pointer until the `shared_ptr` is deleted.  You would normally use this when you want to give the caller an object but you don't want to give them any guarantee that it will still be alive when they want to use it.  `weak_ptr` does have a way to check if the underlying pointer was deleted and it also has the ability to convert it to a `shared_ptr` if the objects exist you so can extend the lifetime of the pointer while you are using it.

EDIT:

In response to the addition on your question in the `smurfClass` all of the of the `smurfAttributes` would be stored as `std::shared_ptr<smurfAttributes>`.  Then in the function that passes out the attribute to others you would return a `std::weak_ptr`.  This way the receiver of the attribute has to try and lock the `weak_ptr` in order to use it and if it can't then it knows it no longer has a valid attribute.

Comment: I agree with you. However, the OP does not want to use them and I do not why!

Comment: @HumamHelfawi How do you get that?  they even ask in their question: `Are there any types of smart pointers that deal with this sort of scenario? e.g. when B is deleted it will null out the reference to itself?`

Comment: @HumamHelfawi OP even said in the comments of the question that he is ok with using `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr`. 
@NathanOliver Good answer, you might want to add an example for `std::weak_ptr` as well, as this question begs for it.

Comment: if he is ok with them and know about them why he simply did not use them!

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Maybe because he simply didn't know about them until now. Maybe he knew them but forgot about them. I can't answer that, only OP can, but I do know that it solves the problem securely and nicely and should be the correct answer for this question and for everyone that will stumble upon this in the future.

Comment: This is helpful, I added some more information to the original post, wondering about passing out a weak_ptr to an object, considering that it is not currently being managed by a smart_ptr.  The code doesn't currently use any weak_ptr or smart_ptr.

Comment: @Derek I added to my answer.  let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: @Derek Your code might not be using it now, but you have to come up with some sort of container or modification of B to accomplish this task. Might as well use what the C++ libraries offers. The way `weak_ptr` works makes it (sort of) thread safe. You still have to synchronize concurrent access to B, but you no longer have to worry about B ceasing to exist while A is in the middle of using it. Checking if B exists and using it afterwards is not sufficient, it might vanish while A is using it in a multithreaded environment. `weak_ptr` solves this by keeping B temporarily alive during access.

Answer (score 0):

I think an example of what you want is the openCV Mat object.
It is a container of an image.  The actual data is stored in a heap (`ucahr* data`).

So when you are about to delete a Mat object the Data will be deleted but the mat itself will still alive.  The Mat itself could be created in the stack and the data inside it would created in the heap.

---

Tiny untested example:

```
class my_container {
    my_container() {
        data = new your_class();
    }

    your_class* get_data() {
        if (data == nullptr) {
            //throw catchable exception or what ever you want
        }
        return data;
    }

    void delete() {
        delete data;
        data = nullptr;
    }
private:
    your_class* data;
}
```

of course this will result in memory leek if you do not free the data before destroying the `my_container` object that is the stack. So you may add to this class the smart pointer design pattern